# save files in registry

Tags: java, file, registry

I want to create and save the file I created such that no one can access to it.
 I already know how to create a file, and so my question is: how can I save this file in the **registry** so that nobody can modify or delete it?

This is to create file:

```
File f = new File("C:\\test.txt");
f.mkdirs();
f.createNewFile();
```

I searched on the web , and this is what I found about saving a file in registry
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090310201348AAihqUQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. People can still change things in the registry
2. The registry is not portable
3. Storing files in the registry is wrong

Don't do it.

Comment: @Calm: how about make in read-only or remove write permissions?

Comment: @CalmSea: That, or you can also make it a hidden file, or even do some simple encryption or add a checksum, if this isn't vital data.

Comment: @abatishchev : I want to make my program trial version , so i want to save the date in a file where the user can not delete it .If he did , he can use the program perminantly

Comment: @CalmSea: The only foolproof* way is to activate it over the internet, then.

Comment: @minitech : I thought in this , but the user should be connected to the internet all the time .

Comment: @CalmSea: Then there's pretty much no difference between a file and a registry key. You can use the registry for a date (which is not a file) but just use whatever's simpler to work with.

Comment: @minitech sorry I did not understand you, what do you mean by registery key?? and how to do this??

Comment: @CalmSea: Keys are what things are stored in in the registry - not files. Just use a file.

Comment: If you're not familiar with the nature of the Windows registry, please just stay the hell away from it.